# No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may have forgotten to define `render` React-Laravel

Tags: reactjs, react-laravel

> When the data returning from "TableRow" Component. I'm getting below error.
> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

Comment: Please add the code using the markdown code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo, you spell `rander()` instead of `render()` in the TableRow component

Comment: yeh!.. OMG!!! it's my fault